# Cannot connect to SQL Server using localhost or (local), ::1 and 127.0.0.1 work

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

When I try to connect to a local SQL Server using localhost or (local), I get the following error:

```
C:\>osql -E -S localhost
[ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Unable to complete login process due to delay
in opening server connection
OS Error 10022 An invalid argument was supplied.
```

Using 127.0.0.1 or ::1, as well as NetBIOS and FQDN names works.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out we had domain DNS related issues that somehow resulted in timeouts resolving **localhost**.

Answer (score -1):

Have you monitored your network connection?
Do you have any firewall blocking connecting to SQL server ports? (1433 or 1434 as the default ports)

If it is possible, please add these ports to your firewall exceptions (or any other user-defined ports for SQL Server)

Comment: Firewall if off.
Please note, that I can connect using 127.0.0.1, ::1, NetBIOS name of FQDN.